# Python program which prints out line number and length of list: Error

Tags: python

Now I'm using while loops to try and do this because I'm not too good at using for loops. As the title reads, I'm trying to print out a table which has the line number next to the length of each line.

Error: When I hit run all I get is the above print out (line and number of words with dashes below). I do not get a series of printouts of y and z
Note: I'm probably making this way harder than it needs to be

Code:

```
list1 = ['Lets go outside','pizza time','show me the money']
list2 = []
print('line   number of words')
print('----   ---------------')
x = 0
len_l1 = len(list1)
while len_l1 > 0:
  split_lis1 = list1[0+x].split(' ')
  list2.append(split_lis1)
  len_l1 -= 1
  x += 1
while len_l1 > 0:
  q = 1
  y = len(list1) - len(list1) + q(x)
  z = len(list2[0+x])
  print(y, z)
  len_l1 -= 1
  x += 1
```

what I want the print out to look like:

```
line   number of words
----   ---------------
0        3
1        2
2        4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Harvey, welcome to SO, if you found any of the answers below that solved your problem, please accept the best answer by ticking the checkbox on the left of the question below the vote arrows. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you might have overcomplicated the solution as there are out of the box Python methods that help you easily solve problems like this. For iteration with indexes, use `enumerate`, in the example below we set the index to start at 1. We can also use some simple string formatting defined in `fmt` to ensure consistent spacings.

```
li = ['Lets go outside','pizza time','show me the money']

print('line   number of words')
print('----   ---------------')
fmt = ('{}     {}')

for idx, sentence in enumerate(li,1):
    no_of_words = len(sentence.split())
    print(fmt.format(idx, no_of_words))
```

Then simple use `split` to split the whitespaces and get the total number of words and let `enumerate` manage the whole thing for you.

```
>>
line   number of words
----   ---------------
1     3
2     2
3     4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['Lets go outside','pizza time','show me the money']
print('line   number of words')
print('----   ---------------')

for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    length = len(list1[i].split(" "))
    print(i + 1, "        ", length)
```

Check out python docs for [range and for](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) details.